# TFS2017 - Build and release management - Error downloading artifacts of XAML build from different project

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm using Team Foundation Server 2017 Update 1.
I have created a release management which contains amongst its artifacts a XAML build from a project which is not the same of the release definition.
Whenever I run the release I have a failure in the download of that artifact.
I have tried to use the same build from a different release management located in the same project of the build as well other vNext builds from different projects and in both case the download works.

Here below the log of the error:

```
An error occurred during download: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildNotFoundException: Requested build 34588 could not be found.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__46.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__43`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__27`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__26`1.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.ArtifactRepository.Build.BuildArtifact.EnsureVersionBelongsToLinkedDefinition(ArtifactDefinition artifactDefinition, BuildHttpClient buildClient, XamlBuildHttpClient xamlBuildClient)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.ArtifactRepository.Build.BuildArtifact.Download(ArtifactDefinition artifactDefinition, String localFolderPath)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Plugin.Release.AgentArtifactDownloader.Download(ArtifactDefinition artifactDefinition, Uri workingFolder)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Plugin.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<DownloadArtifacts>b__1()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Windows.Implementation.RetryExecutor.Execute(Action action)
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildNotFoundException: Requested build 34588 could not be found.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__46.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__43`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__27`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__26`1.MoveNext()<---
```

Does anybody saw something similar and have an idea of how to fix it?

Comment: It's entirely possible that the scenario you're trying isn't supported -- XAML builds are deprecated.

Comment: In the release definition I have the problem there is another xaml build which is defined in the same project as the release definition and it is working fine

Comment: Right. The scenario is "I want to access a XAML build from a release definition across team project boundaries." That may be an unsupported scenario.

Comment: Well, in my opinion, if the system does not support this scenario, it should show a better error messages :). Actually I suspect that there is a bug in TFS 2017, but I wanted to be sure I'm not doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a bug in TFS 2017 which has been fixed in TFS 2017 Update 2.

More information about the bug can be found [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/75042/error-downloading-artifacts-of-xaml-build-from-dif.html):

To fix the problem you have to update the TFS agent(s) to the version 2.117.2.

Answer (score 0):

After go through more details and tests, got the same result and error info as you. 
There is no extra setup for XAML build in "across team project" scenario.

> Noticed you have also submitted  a bug to
>   **DeveloperCommunity-TFS**--[Error downloading artifacts of XAML build from different project](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/75042/error-downloading-artifacts-of-xaml-build-from-dif.html)

It's the right place for submitting bug to TFS team directly, the developers and PM will follow up in time. You just need to pay attention to that site.

I'm afraid this may be an unsupported scenario  on XAML build with high probability. Besides, *Daniel* is right XAML build is a legacy build system and which is deprecated. Highly recommend you to move the new task based system.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for the help, unfortuntely I had already tried to see the build through web api and I saw that the build is found when I put the correct project, the error occurs when I put the project in which the build is located (obviously :)). Unfortunately the failing function is not a code I developed but it is a Microsoft one.

Comment: @MattiaMagosso After go through more details and tests, got the same result and error info as you. 
There is no extra setup for XAML build in "across team project" scenario.  
  Noticed you have also submitted  a bug to
 **DeveloperCommunity-TFS**.It's the right place for submitting bug to TFS team directly, the developers and PM will follow up in time. You just need to pay attention to that site. More details please see my update answer.